# Terraform Plan Results in No Message when there's No change

Tags: terraform

I'm running 'terraform plan' twice using playbook in ansible Tower - 1st before running terraform import, and 2nd after the import to detect any change. In the 2nd run when there's any change (it detects) it gives a message  - "Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy." But when there's no change, the terraform plan shows no such message (expecting 0 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy). The only message I get in the last is this: "You can apply this plan to save these new output values to the Terraform state, without changing any real infrastructure."  Can anyone say why or what to do to get the message?

To Test, I changed tag for one of the resources and ran the playbook. Then it showed 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy. I have checked the plan file using 'terraform show <plan_file_name.plan>, there's also no such message when there's no change.

Answer (score 0):

[image: sample image] You can use "No Changes" keyword to find if there is no change in Infrastructure. I am using this as bash command.

```
terraform plan -out plan.out
terraform show plan.out | grep -q "No changes"
```

Comment: Thanks. But this will show if there any "no changes" inside the plan file which I did search with terraform show <plan_file_name.plan> command. But there's no such item. Can you please think of any other reason why this is it and how to fix it?

Comment: If you're expecting for 0-add,0-change,0-delete - It is not available. I have updated my answer with an Image. That will be the output when there is no change in Infrastructure. I am using those two commands to check for keyword "No Changes".

Comment: thanks, in my case no such message ("no changes") is there inside the plan file either. That's the issue.

Comment: Which Terraform version you are using. Also could you please post the output of your terraform plan along with your question. FYI. I am using Terraform v1.3.6

Comment: I'm using version 1.2.7. The plan - 
Changes to Outputs:
  - sg_list= [] -> null
  - subnet= [
      - {- sub_name = "TM-Access-Compute-PrivateSubnet1B-us-west-2b"
          - vpc = "TM-Access-Compute"
        }] -> null
  - subnet_group_ids = [
      - [ - null,
          - null, ],
      - [- null,
          - null,
        ],] -> null
  - vpc_name         = {
      - TM-Access-Compute = {
          - vpc_name = "TM-Access-Compute"
        } } -> null

You can apply this plan to save these new output values to the Terraform
state, without changing any real infrastructure.